# Uncaught TypeError: exists is not a function when attempting to use serial port in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, serial-port, ionic2

I want to use the serial port in my Ionic 2  project. I use [Cordova BLE](https://github.com/evothings/cordova-ble) for iOS and Android but Cordova BLE does not support Windows 10. First I used `npm install serialport` in node-module. That's fine. When I use .js file and nodejs to work I can get data in the serial port via ex. 'COM3'. Below is my JavaScript code:

```
SerialPort =require("serialport")

var socketServer;
var serialPort;
var portName = 'COM3';
var sendData = "";

function startServer() {

serialListener();
}

function serialListener() {

var receivedData = "";

serialPort = new SerialPort(portName, {
    baudrate: 9600,
    dataBits: 8,
    parity: 'none',
    stopBits: 1,
    flowControl: false
});

serialPort.on("open", function () {

    console.log('open serial communication');

    // Listens to incoming data
    serialPort.on('data', function (data) {

        receivedData += data.toString();

        if (receivedData.indexOf('E') >= 0 && receivedData.indexOf('B') >= 0) {

            sendData = receivedData.substring(receivedData.indexOf('B') + 1,  receivedData.indexOf('E'));

            receivedData = '';
        }

        // send the incoming data to browser with websockets.
        //socketServer.emit('update', sendData);

        console.log(sendData);
    });
 });
  }
  exports.start = startServer;
```

When I run in nodejs as like `node index.js` Every think is OK. I easily get serial port data.

But now I can not use this method in TypeScript. My .ts code is below.

```
   import { Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core';

   declare function require(name: string);

   var SerialPort=require('serialport');



 @Injectable()
 export class ServicePort {

public socketServer: any;
public serialPort: any;
public portName: any = 'COM3';
public sendData: any = "";

public constructor() {

    console.log("Geldi");

    console.log(SerialPort);
    //this.serialListener();
}

serialListener() {

    var receivedData = "";

    this.serialPort = new SerialPort(this.portName, {
        baudrate: 9600,
        dataBits: 8,
        parity: 'none',
        stopBits: 1,
        flowControl: false
    });

    this.serialPort.on("open", () => {

        console.log('open serial communication');

        this.serialPort.on('data', (data)=> {

            receivedData += data.toString();

            if (receivedData.indexOf('E') >= 0 && receivedData.indexOf('B') >= 0) {

                this.sendData = receivedData.substring(receivedData.indexOf('B') + 1, receivedData.indexOf('E'));

                receivedData = '';
            }

            // send the incoming data to browser with websockets.
            //socketServer.emit('update', sendData);

            console.log(this.sendData);
        });
    });
}
}
```

I call above .ts like this:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {ServicePort} from '../serialport/servicePort';


 @Component({
   selector: 'page-home',
   templateUrl: 'home.html',
   providers: [ServicePort]
 })
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private platform: Platform,         private portservice: ServicePort) {

    this.portservice.serialListener();
  }
 }
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: exists is not a function
at Function.getRoot (main.js:99030)
at bindings (main.js:98926)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:111823)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:111856)
at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:112063)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:112527)
at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:113162)
at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
```

Can I use JavaScript function in my TypeScript for my Ionic 2 project or can I use the serial port in TypeScript?

Comment: anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

To use a javascript module in typescript you need to have a declarations file of the module. Check [github of definitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped).

Serialport types is available:[npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/serialport)

Just do:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/serialport
```

Also ensure your tsconfig.json has:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
]
```

To import:

```
import * as SerialPort from 'serialport';
```

Comment: I take this mistake :   Uncaught TypeError: exists is not a function
    at Function.getRoot (bindings.js:153)
    at bindings (bindings.js:55)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bindings.js:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bindings.js:34)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 18e72d9…:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (serialport.js:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (serialport.js:474)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 18e72d9…:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:59007)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 18e72d9…:19)

Comment: are you calling a function `exists`?

Comment: no just I call  as  console.log(SerialPort) for try. Can you use in ionic 2. Because its not working in my project.

Comment: I havent used serialport.. But the above steps are used to use a javascript module in ionic 2.. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/serialport/serialport-tests.ts maybe this will help

Comment: How can use in ionic2 , How can call this method, because my javascript is working in nodejs.

Comment: This is big problem for me, I spend so time :)

Comment: This just working in cordova project as android,ios and windos phone, but not supported windows 10. when I use BluetoothSerial  I take (plugin is not istall) error in win10

Comment: Do you have any idea @suraj

Comment: Ok, can we use javascript module in typescript. I can read data from serialport in javascript but I want to emit data from typescript

Comment: Hi @suraj, Can I create bridge between javascript and typsecript. Do you have any idea.

Comment: The only way is to have a declarations file for the corresponding javascript. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html and then import into your typescript similar to my answer

Comment: what do you think about my problem to above code @suraj

Comment: for that plugin, try installing with `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-ble --save` and in your ts file declare global object `var evothings:any` and try calling the function if it works.. I have no idea about windows 10 or the actual plugin

Comment: Hi @suraj, When I use     BLE.connect('12:34:56:78:9A:BC').subscribe(peripheralData => {
            this.message = peripheralData;
            console.log(peripheralData);
        },
            peripheralData => {
                this.message = peripheralData;
                console.log('disconnected');
            });  its say plugin_not_install for windows

Comment: I dont think ionic will help even BLE is android and ios https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/ble/

Comment: Yeah, But when  open BLE plugin .js file that say is sported for windows 8.1, and I try work to running in windows 8.1 device that say also plugin_not install @suraj.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/platform-setup/windows-setup.html have you done the part about `Windows Universal Apps`?

Comment: Yes of course I install also same plugin is working as like camera and barcode scanner. But serial port or ble to get data in bloutooth is not working. Why ionic not create serialport for windows its engrossing @suraj

Comment: sry I am not sure

Comment: you could check in their forum https://forum.ionicframework.com/ for windows 10 support..good luck